# How to display the x-axis values either ascending OR descending order in primefaces bar chart

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jqplot

I'm using Primefaces 5.1 bar chart and displaying fine. But the problem is am getting DATE values (x-axis) are in-order.
like, 21-08-2015,19-08-2015,27-08-2015,01-08-2015,10-08-2015.

I want display the x-axis (Date) values either ascending OR descending order. How can i do this in correct way???

I've attached my code & screen shot the graph.
MY CODE:

```
function ext() {
this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
        textColor : '#ffffff'
    };




this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = {
        textColor : '#ffffff'

    };

this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.angle= 90 ;
this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = '%b %#d, %y' ;      



this.cfg.axes.xaxis.labelOptions = {
        textColor : '#ffffff'
    };
this.cfg.axes.yaxis.labelOptions = {
        textColor : '#ffffff'
    };  
this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions = {
        barWidth : 30
    };

this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.angle= 90 ;

}
```

[image]